# Setting default virtual host on apache

Tags: apache, web, development-environment

I have set my local development machine to use apache to serve virtual hosts based on folders using the following setup in apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/ben/Sites
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/ben/Sites/%-2/htdocs
    UseCanonicalName Off

    <Directory "/Users/ben/Sites/*/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible to set a default so that when the server is accessed externally it chooses a particular one of those folders?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to add a *:80 virtualhost *after* this one that doesn't use VirtualDocumentRoot at all and has a specific DocumentRoot. It will be matched only when the ServerName/ServerAlias matches the hostname used by your external clients.